# CsvMapper Serialize Null Fields as Literal null

Tags: jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I would like CsvMapper to map null instance fields as literal null (as shown in Desired Output). For example:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class);
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema.withUseHeader(true));
        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setFirstName("John");
        pojo.setLastName(null);
        String csv = writer.writeValueAsString(pojo);
        System.out.println(csv);
    }

    @Data
    public static class Pojo {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
firstName,lastName
John,
```

**Desired Output**

```
firstName,lastName
John,null
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a better answer

```java
CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class).withNullValue("null");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I am using jackson-dataformat-csv:2.12.4.

The class CsvMapper extends ObjectMapper. Therefore, CsvMapper lets you register a module as well as ObjectMapper.

```
 SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new EmptyStringDeserializer());


      csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
            csvMapper
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .registerModule(module)
```

So you need to create your deserializer as usual:

```
    public class EmptyStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    
    
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            if (p.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING && "".equals(p.getText())) {
                return null;
            }
    
            return StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done some digging into the `CsvMapper` code and found out it uses `DefaultSerializerProvider`.

Thus I overrode the nullSerializer with a custom `JsonSerializer`

```java
public class CustomNullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeString("null");
    }
}
```

Then modified the CsvMapper

```java
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
sp.setNullValueSerializer(new CustomNullSerializer());
mapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);
```